# Adding OnClickListener in a listview using prepopulated or external database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to build an Onclicklistener in listview using prepopulated database. I don't how to add some onclicklistener in this. Can someone show me how. Thanks!

DataListView.java

```
package com.example.thetrial;

import java.io.IOException;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.database.Cursor;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.ListView;  
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;  

public class DataListView extends Activity {  
DBHelper dbhelper;  

@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.main);    
String[] from = new String[] { "_id", "comm", "desc" };  
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.TextView1, R.id.TextView2, R.id.TextView3 };  
dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);  
  try {  
    dbhelper.createDataBase();  
   } catch (IOException e) {  
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
   }  

Cursor c = dbhelper.getData();  

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, c, from, to);  

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);  

list.setAdapter(adapter);  
}  

}
```

This is my DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.thetrial;


import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStream;  
import java.io.OutputStream;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.database.Cursor;  
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;  
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;  
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  

 private static String DB_NAME = "trialeleventh";  
 private static int DB_Version = 2;
 private SQLiteDatabase db;  
 private final Context context;  
 private String DB_PATH;  

 public DBHelper(Context context) {  
  super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_Version);  
  this.context = context;  
  DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";  
 }  

 public void createDataBase() throws IOException {  

          boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();  
          if (dbExist) {  
         try {  
           copyDataBase();  
          } catch (IOException e) {  
           throw new Error("Error copying database");  
          }  
          } else {  
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         if (db.isOpen()){
             db.close();
             try {  
               copyDataBase();  
              } catch (IOException e) {  
               throw new Error("Error copying database");  
              }  
         } else {
         try {  
           copyDataBase();  
          } catch (IOException e) {  
           throw new Error("Error copying database");  
          }  
         }
          }
          }  

 private boolean checkDataBase() {  
  File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);  
  return dbFile.exists();  
 }  

 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {  

  InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);  
  String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
  OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);  
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
  int length;  
  while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
   myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);  
  }  

  // Close the streams  
  myOutput.flush();  
  myOutput.close();  
  myInput.close();  

 }  

 public Cursor getData() {  
  String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
  db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);  
  onUpgrade(db, DB_Version, 2);
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM linux_comm", null);  
    return c;  
 }  

 @Override  
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {  
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
 }  

 @Override  
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Log.d ("onUpgrade first log", Integer.toString(db.getVersion()));

    if (oldVersion == 1) {

        DB_Version = 2;
        db.setVersion(2);
        Log.d ("onUpgrade second log", Integer.toString(db.getVersion()));

    }

    else {
        Log.d("onUpgrade", "else-clause: Already upgraded!");
 }  
 }
}
```

I'm using SQLite Database Broswer. Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: You can use setOnItemClickListener for any list. Database is not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just setOnItemClickListener to your list like below.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        //Write onClick logic here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use   setOnItemClickListener

```
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

             TextView text = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from)); 
             String from = text.getText().toString();
             Toast.makeText(DataListView.this,
                                from, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // your Code here

        }

    });
```

Comment: What if I want to start another intent, and the data that will be seen is from the inside or other column of the id? Can you show me some how?

Comment: I couldnt understand. Do you mean to say You need to go to another activity with that particular list id details ?

Comment: Like that. In my db table there are 6 columns on what i've posted it only list the first three columns data. So if i-click on that item i will be directed to a page where in the other 3 columns data will be shown.